# BigQuery reader Tensorflow accessing data with oauth

Tags: python, flask, tensorflow, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I want to use the BigQuery reader from Tensorflow to access data from someone else's project in GCP. What am I doing wrong?

In order to this I use a Flask app where the user can provide permission in the form of OAuth2Credentials. This permission works fine when testing it on the BigQuery API. When using the BigQuery reader for my own data it also works fine. However when initializing the BigQery reader for someone else's data I get a permission denied error.

This is my code to get permissions

```
from oauth2client import client
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
from apiclient import discovery

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    global service
    if 'credentials' not in flask.session:
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('oauth2callback'))
    credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials.from_json(flask.session['credentials'])
    if credentials.access_token_expired:
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('oauth2callback'))
    else:
        http_auth = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        service = discovery.build('bigquery', 'v2', http_auth)
        return 'ok'

@app.route('/oauth2callback')
def oauth2callback():
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
            'client_secret.json',
            scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery '
            + 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery.insertdata '
            + 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform', 
            redirect_uri=flask.url_for('oauth2callback', _external=True))
    if 'code' not in flask.request.args:
        auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
        return flask.redirect(auth_uri)
    else:
        auth_code = flask.request.args.get('code')
        credentials = flow.step2_exchange(auth_code)
        flask.session['credentials'] = credentials.to_json()
        return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('index'))
```

If I run code to access the bigquery API this works fine so I woudn't expect any problem with the permissions:

```
response = service.projects().list().execute()
```

But when creating the BigQuery reader with this code:

```
from tensorflow.contrib.cloud.python.ops.bigquery_reader_ops import BigQueryReader
import tensorflow as tf

reader = BigQueryReader(project_id=project_id,
        dataset_id=dataset_id,
        table_id=table_id,
        timestamp_millis=millis,
        num_partitions=10,
        features=features_dict)

queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(reader.partitions())
```

I get a permission denied error:

```
Permission denied: Error executing an HTTP request (HTTP response code 403, error code 0, error message '')
when reading schema for project_id:dataset_id.table_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The authentication of the TF BigQuery connector is not very well documented and I can't seem to find the relevant pieces of code, however my guess is that it uses [application default credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials).

This is different from the raw BigQuery call, where you pass them explicitly when you build the `service`.

One thing you can try, when you perform `credentials.to_json()`, dump the result into a file, and point a `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to it. Not sure if that's gonna fix it, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: For my application I also need the default credentials to access data from the datastore so overriding them would create a new problem

Comment: Hmm that's a pickle. But perhaps if you can confirm that that's indeed where TF gets the credentials from, you could start thinking how to go around it, ie by splitting it into two different microservices, each with own default creds or sth. I assume the auth is meant to be dynamic and sharing the dataset with your default service account is not an option?